# What is the correct way of "clearing" a ComboBox's index?

Tags: vb.net

```
Me.cmbSomeCombo.Text = ""
Me.cmbSomeCombo.SelectedIndex = -1
```

**vs**

```
Me.cmbSomeCombo.SelectedIndex = -1
Me.cmbSomeCombo.Text = ""
```

I'm running into the question of does setting the `Text` of the `ComboBox` cause the `SelectedIndex` to change? And if so, what does it change the index to?

**OR**

Does setting the `SelectedIndex` to -1 cause the `Text` to be `""`?

I'm trying to figure out which is the "correct" way to "clear" the selected index of a `ComboBox`.

**EDIT:** The `DropDownStyle` of the `ComboBox` is `DropDown`.

Comment: It depends on the DropDownStyle you selected, you'll need to document that.

Comment: @HansPassant Out of curiousity, why/how is it dependent the DropDownStyle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question yes setting the selected Index to -1 does causes the text of the combo box to be "". This is how I tested it

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
    Dim string1 As String = ComboBox1.Text
End Sub
```

At the end of this procedure string1 will be equal to "".

Comment: Does it also happen in the reverse? Meaning, does setting the text to "" change the SelectedIndex to -1?